# Metasploit Meterpreter how to restore/create new session?

Tags: android, metasploit, meterpreter

I created an apk for Android with Metasploit. Started with host ip and port and opened the "receiver terminal"

A lot of things worked well when executing the apk but after some time the session died. Now I don't know how to create a new one.

Repeated the steps in the terminal but it does not work. Didn't change a thing on my android

Also is there an option to install a backdoor to my phone forever?

Comment: When asking for troubleshooting help, you need to include a lot more info. Like, what commands you used, actual outputs, what's working, what's not working, etc. You don't describe what the APK does, what kind of payload you used. You don't explain if the APK is still running or if you reran the APK on the Android. Start working through some basic troubleshooting steps.